# What should be semantic structure of a "horizontal" headless table?

Tags: html

I know how to achieve this kind of table with `rowspan` for `td` in the first column, but I'm wondering what is the best **semantic** approach to this.

Should I maybe create 3 tables (as [this site](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_mi_a1-8776.php) has) and use main sections as heads of those, like this:

```
<th scope="col">Section 1</th>
```

[image: HTML table structure]

Comment: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/

Comment: `scope="col"` is wrong. "Section 1" is not the heading for the column, but for the cells in the two rows to its right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're pretty close. For a row-level header, you'll want to use `scope="row"` instead. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to make a `<thead>` that is vertical:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" rowspan="2">Section 1</th>
      <td>Subsection 1A</td>
      <td>Content of subsection 1A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Subsection 1B</td>
      <td>Content of subsection 1B</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```